# 2 classes need another class to exist first. How can I solve this circular class dependency?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx, collision-detection, circular-dependency

In my `GameWorld` class I initialize an item `Rectangle` in the constructor.

```
item1 = new Rectangle(GameRenderer.obstacle3.getX() - GameRenderer.generator2.getValue2(), GameRenderer.generator2.getValue1(), 5, 5);
```

The problem I'm having is that to initialize `GameRenderer.obstacle3` a `GameWorld` must already exist, and to create a `GameWorld`, `GameRenderer.obstacle3` must not be null.

In other words: `GameRenderer.obstacle3` needs GameWorld to exist first but `GameWorld` needs `GameRenderer.obstacle3` to exist first.

That is why I got a `NullPointerException`.

I use the rectangle for collision detection, i.e.

```
if (Intersector.overlaps(wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), item1)) { 
                GameRenderer.DoublePointsActive = true;
                addScore(5);
}
```

I don't know how I can solve this issue with reorganizing at least as possible.

Comment: This probably is not a good question for stackoverflow. Maybe try https://codereview.stackexchange.com for questions like this in the future. For this specific problem, you probably want to remove GameWorld's dependency on an obstacle, or visa-versa. Try drawing out your dependencies with pencil and paper. Ask why the GameWorld needs to know about the obstacle, or visa-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid coupling these classes like this. Maybe you should rethink about your design. Why is obstacle3 member of GameRenderer and not member of GameWorld, for example? An obstacle doesn't seen to fit as a member of a renderer.